# using limit in subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use `LIMIT` inside a sub query in `MySQL`, but each time I run the query I get `[42000][1235] This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME sub query'` error.

I'm trying to get only the first `20` id returned from the sub query.

```
SELECT c.collection_name, t.raw
FROM   collections c
  JOIN member_of_collection m
    ON c.collection_id = m.collection_id
  JOIN citations t
    ON m.citation_id = t.citation_id
WHERE m.collection_id IN
   (
    SELECT count(*) FROM collections c
      JOIN member_of_collection m
        ON c.collection_id = m.collection_id
      JOIN citations t
        ON t.citation_id = m.citation_id
    WHERE length(trim(t.raw)) > 0
          AND RIGHT(c.collection_name, length(c.collection_name) - 4) IN (SELECT cat_name from cats_cat)
          AND left(t.raw, 3) != '–––'
    GROUP BY c.collection_name
    ORDER BY count(*) desc
    LIMIT 20
  );
```

Comment: `LIMIT 20` need to be ourtside of sub-query.

Comment: Why are you comparing a `collection_id` to a `count(*)` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `join`:

```
SELECT c.collection_name, t.raw
FROM collections c JOIN
     member_of_collection m
     ON c.collection_id = m.collection_id JOIn
     citations t
     ON m.citation_id = t.citation_id JOIN
     (SELECT c.collection_id, count(*) 
      FROM collections c JOIN
           member_of_collection m
           ON c.collection_id = m.collection_id JOIN
           citations t
           ON t.citation_id = m.citation_id
      WHERE length(trim(t.raw)) > 0 AND
            RIGHT(c.collection_name, length(c.collection_name) - 4) IN (SELECT cat_name from cats_cat)
          AND left(t.raw, 3) != '–––'
      GROUP BY c.collection_id
      ORDER BY count(*) desc
      LIMIT 20
     ) cc
     ON m.collection_id = cc.collection_id;
```

This makes a couple of assumptions:

- You really want to compare `collection_id` to a *collection_id*, not a count.
- Grouping by the collection name and collection id is the same thing.

Comment: Those assumptions are correct. I made a typo.
This solved it.

Thank you.